# Show that $x≤2 \sin(πx)$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I want to show that $x≤2 \sin(πx)$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$.

When plotting $x$ and $2\sin(\pi x)$ (below) it seems clear that this inequality should hold. However I got stuck showing it analytically. I tried taking the derivative of $\frac{x}{\sin(\pi x)}$ to show that the quotient is an increasing function whose maximum is less than 2 but it wasn't clear from the resulting expression:

$
\frac{\sin(\pi x)-\pi x \cos(\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x)}
$

that this must be the case. Similarly I tried to show $2\sin(πx) - x\geq 0$ for all $x$. I also thought how to use that for real numbers $\sin(x) \leq x$ but couldn't make progress.

[image]

Comment: Use the well known $\frac{2}{\pi }w \le \sin w$, $0 \le w \le \frac{\pi }{2}$, with $w=\pi x$ an you obtain a stronger result.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your quotient is not increasing, as the slope of the sine falls.

But rather: The slope of $\sin(\pi x)$ in $x=0$ is $\pi>1/2$. So the inequality holds at least on a smaller interval.
Equality of slope is reached at
$$ \pi\cos(\pi x) = 1/2 $$
so
$$ \pi x = \arccos(1/(2\pi))$$
so
$$ x\approx 0.449 $$. So for $x=0.44$ the slope of the sine is still larger, so the inequality holds at least on $[0,0.44]$. Also as the sine is non decreasing on $[0.44,1/2]$ we might now calculate $\sin(\pi 0.44)\approx 0.982>0.98$. But since $x/2 \leq 1/4 < 0.98$ on $[0,1/2]$ we get that the inequality holds on the whole interval.